# countif sum of 2 columns is greater than another 2

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have a problem with excel functions. I want to count how many sums of column A & B are greater than column C & D

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| :---- | :------: | -----: | -----: |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| :---- | :------: | -----: | -----: |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| :---- | :------: | -----: | -----: |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 0 |

In this example the right answer is 2. (The second and third row).
How can i type it to a function?

Answer (score 2):

Use `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--((A1:A4+B1:B4)>(C1:C4+D1:D4)))
```

[image]